# windows ReadFile() doesn't return until reading sizeToRead value

Tags: c++, c, windows, serial-port

In serial communication, `ReadFile` doesn't return until reading as many as `sizeToRead` parameter.

It is so weird, because actually until yesterday, it works normally with same code, same laptop, returning though it doesn't receive as many as `sizeToRead` but any bytes.

But today my code show weird symptom like this.

```
serialHandle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM1",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    0);

DCB serialInfo = {0};

GetCommState(serialHandle, &serialInfo)

serialInfo.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
serialInfo.BaudRate = CBR_19200;
serialInfo.fBinary = TRUE;
serialInfo.fParity = TRUE;          
serialInfo.fErrorChar = TRUE;
serialInfo.fNull = TRUE;
serialInfo.fAbortOnError = FALSE;   //TODO
serialInfo.ByteSize = 8;
serialInfo.Parity = SPACEPARITY;
serialInfo.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
serialInfo.ErrorChar = 0xFF;    

SetCommState(serialHandle, &serialInfo

ReadFile(serialHandle, buffer, numberOfBytesToRead, &numOfBytesRead, NULL)
```

numberOfBytesToRead is 256, So ReadFile return after getting 256 bytes

Comment: Reaearch what controls blocking vs. non-blocking behavior.

Comment: I know block and non-block but, as i know default is block and ReadFile Must return if any byte is received, But now it seems to wait for being received 256 bytes but any bytes.

Comment: No, that's not how ReadFile() works when you use it on a serial port.  The only guarantee you have is that it returns at least 1 byte.  You cannot ignore your *numOfBytesRead* variable, you'll get whatever happens to be available in the driver's receive buffer.  Or the ReadFile() return value, **never** ignore failure returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReadFile can return before reading numOfBytesRead based on a timeout, see SetCommTimeouts. If you have not initialized the timeout settings then you inherit whatever was set by other programs. So for consistent behavior 1you should call this API when you open the COM port.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that `COMMTIMEOUTS.ReadIntervalTimeout` was 0. that is why `ReadFile()` doesn't return until being received numberOfBytesToRead