# Serial communication waits for the first time until the size of the reading is filled asynchronous communication c++

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm trying to read from serial port. I opened a file with an overlap flag so that reading and writing will not be blocked by each other.
I have set up an array of 400 bytes to read, and I call a function with a size of 400.
For some reason for the first time, only after filling in all 400 bytes in the array the function returns the array. in the rest of the readings the function immediately returns the array according to the size sent.
Of course for the read and write functions I run from a separate threads.

I tried 2 different functions, both of which work the same

Here is the first reading function i tried:

```
int GetData(unsigned char* lpBuf, DWORD dwToRead)
{
    OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 };
    DWORD dwRead;
    BOOL fRes;

    // Create this writes OVERLAPPED structure hEvent.
    osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (osReader.hEvent == NULL)
        // Error creating overlapped event handle.
        return FALSE;

    // Issue write.
    if (!ReadFile(hCom, lpBuf, dwToRead, &dwRead, &osReader))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            // WriteFile failed, but it isn't delayed. Report error and abort.
            fRes = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            // Write is pending.
            if (!GetOverlappedResult(hCom, &osReader, &dwRead, TRUE))
                fRes = FALSE;
            else
                // Write operation completed successfully.
                fRes = TRUE;
        }
    }
    else
        // WriteFile completed immediately.
        fRes = TRUE;

    CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);
    return dwRead;
}
```

Here is the second reading function i tried:

```
int GetData(unsigned char* lpInBuffer, DWORD dwBytesRead)
{
    COMSTAT ComStat;
    DWORD dwErrorFlags;
    OVERLAPPED m_osRead;
    memset(&m_osRead, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    m_osRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    ClearCommError(hCom, &dwErrorFlags, &ComStat);
    //dwBytesRead = min(dwBytesRead, (DWORD)ComStat.cbInQue);
    if(!dwBytesRead) return FALSE;
    BOOL bReadStatus;
    bReadStatus = ReadFile(hCom, lpInBuffer, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesRead, &m_osRead);
    if(!bReadStatus)
        // if the ReadFile function returns FALSE
    {
        if(GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            // GetLastError() function returns ERROR_IO_PENDING, indicating that the serial port is reading
        {
            GetOverlappedResult(hCom, &m_osRead, &dwBytesRead, true);
            //WaitForSingleObject(m_osRead.hEvent,2000);
            // Wait until the read operation is completed or the delay has reached 2 seconds using the WaitForSingleObject function
            // When the serial read operation is completed, m_osRead's hEvent event becomes a signal
            return dwBytesRead;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return dwBytesRead;
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to help me?

Comment: [*Serial.sys continues to transfer bytes until the requested number of bytes are transferred or a time-out event occurs.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/serports/setting-read-and-write-timeouts-for-a-serial-device) - read also about [`SERIAL_TIMEOUTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddser/ns-ntddser-_serial_timeouts?redirectedfrom=MSDN) how control this.

Comment: *Of course for the read and write functions I run from a separate threads* - of course this not need

Comment: When reading from a communications device, the behavior of  `ReadFile` is determined by the current communication time-out as set and retrieved by using the `SetCommTimeouts` and `GetCommTimeouts` functions. Unpredictable results can occur if you fail to set the time-out values.  Read [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947356/windows-readfile-doesnt-return-until-reading-sizetoread-value) and tell me if it helps you.